# Confused about the correct model specification given the study design (fully-crossed factors with nested repeated measures)

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, nested-models

**THE ISSUE**

Apologies in advance, being primarily a biologist and only tangentially a statistician I hesitate to ask this question for fear of overly complicating a simple situation. That said, I have been reading through some posts trying to figure out the proper way to formulate a model for an experimental design where there are two factors that are fully crossed and then another that is nested within the second factor.

Below is a diagram of the design -- the experimental focus is on the Factor Unit (there are 10, only depicting a subset here for clarity), each unit has observations in one of 13 equal-duration phases (only depicting 3 here for clarity, these are related to moon cycles so could be reated as either a continuous or categorical variable), and nested within these phases are 5 randomly selected days nested within cycle. The response is a count (whole number integer) for each unit-day combination.

[image]

Given the issues with nesting and repeated measures, I am struggling to determine the proper model specification.

**WHAT I'VE COME UP WITH**

Here are formulations that I can come up with:

1. Ignoring all existence of nested effects/non-independence and just model everything as a fixed effect (Equivalent to a two-way ANOVA):

```
 CountPerDay ~ Unit + Phase + Unit*Phase
```

2. Specify the model as in #1, but also include days as a random factor to account for temporal autocorrelation between days:

```
 CountPerDay ~ Unit + Phase + Unit*Phase + (1|DaySinceStart)
```

3. Specify the model as a one-way ANOVA, where unit is the fixed effect and time is the random effect: (Equivalent to a nested ANOVA)

```
 CountPerDay ~ Unit + (1|Phase) + (1|Phase:DaySinceStart)
```

4. Specify the model as a one-way ANOVA, where phase is the fixed effect and unit is the random effect: (Equivalent of a repeated measures ANOVA)

```
CountPerDay ~ Phase + (1|Unit) + (1|Phase:DaySinceStart)
```

**MAIN QUESTIONS**

1. Given that the interest is in how the detections vary as a function of both space (Unit) and time (Phase) what is the proper approach for this experimental design? (*I think, but am not certain, that either #1 or #2 are the proper formulations*)
2. If each Unit had a unique Phase * Day combination (depicted below) could phase still be considered crossed with unit or would this be instead considered a nested design that lacks crossing as in the image depicted below?

[image]

3. How would the answer to Q1 differ if the experimental design was fully nested and lacked crossing? (*I think, but am not certain, that #3 would be the proper formulation and that #4 would only be legitimate if Unit were somehow nested in Phase and Day)*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `Unit` the "experimental unit"? That is, do you study a population of `Unit`s of which you sampled 10 at the start of the study and then you observe them over time, i.e. over `Day`s within `Phase`s?

Comment: @dipetkov Yes, exactly right.

Comment: Can you explain how you expect your response to change over time (DaySinceStart)? Is there a reason you would not treat this as continuous?

Comment: Do you have previous data or simulated data to explain what patterns you expect to observe and want to model? It would help to have an idea of what CountPerDay may look like for one unit over the course of a year.

Comment: Does `DaySinceStart` start at Phase 1, Day 1 or does it re-start at Day 1 for each Phase?

Comment: @mkt There are 13 phases and, within each, 10 days are randomly selected since measuring all 28-days of each phase at each unit is not feasible. The 10 days that are randomly selected for one Unit/Phase combination do not necessarily match that of any other Unit/Phase combination (e.g., In Phase 1, Unit 1 may be sampled on days 1,3,7,10,15,16,21,25,28, Unit 2 may be sampled on days 2, 3,6,13,15,19,24,25,28, and so on...)

Comment: @dipetkov I don't know exactly how count per day would vary over the course of a year other than it may fluctuate seasonally due to changes in behavior (e.g., nesting versus non-nesting or migration period versus stationary period). See my reply to mkt, I think maybe that is a matter of definition (?)

Comment: You've written the question is a very abstract way. That's not necessarily helpful and I suspect that there is a lot of relevant domain knowledge to make this question answerable. For example, "fluctuating seasonality" implies that E(count) during two phases in the same season might be very similar. As @mkt says, the effect of time is often best modeled in a smooth nonlinear way rather than by considering time to be cut into discrete sections and treated as categorical.

Comment: @dipetkov I did not mean to be abstract, but also am trying to make my question general enough that it is applicable to others out there who may have a similar question. I think it is a valid point that time should be treated continuously and appreciate that advice.  In this case, because only 10 of 28 days are sampled per phase per unit, would we be able to include days since start as continuous due to gaps in the time series? Sorry for a potentially dumb question. I was thinking of time discreetly so my OP was about how to properly specify the crossed/nested aspects given that assumption.